# Throw a warning/error when implicitly converting from X to Y in Visual C#

Tags: c#, types

Is it possible to selectively treat certain implicit type conversions as errors, or at least generate warnings when they happen?

Bad:

```
long x = 5; //warning, 5 is an int
float f = 10;// warning, 10 is an int
```

---

Good:

```
long x = 5L; //correct, no warning
float f = 10f; //correct, no warning
```

Edit: removed reference to bugs, since that isn't the point of the question, and isn't helpful.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "subtle bugs" this may cause.

Comment: The main case that comes to mind, albeit only somewhat related, is assignment of an integer division result to a floating point variable; i.e. `double x = 1/2` will give you `x==0`.

Comment: @DanBryant: Right... but anyone with even a small amount of experience knows not to do that. That's not subtle; it's basic integer arithmetic.

Comment: @Ed implicit conversions can be defined between any types, not just the built in numeric types

Comment: @Buttons: But if you go out of your way to define an implicit conversion why would you want to be warned about using it?

Comment: @Ed If I am making heavy use of someone else's code which I can't change, and makes liberal use of them.

Comment: @Buttons, I'm not sure if you're open to disassembling and reassembling the third party code, but you might try tagging the implicit conversions that are causing trouble with an [Obsolete] attribute.

Comment: @Buttons: But of course, nothing like that is mentioned by the OP.  In fact, his two examples are identical; after the assignment they are all the correct type and identical.  Seems like much ado about nothing to me, but meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Visual Studio Premium+, you may be able to create a [Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264939.aspx) ruleset to handle this during build time.

You could also write your own [VS.NET extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393694.aspx) and possible integrate with [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn) to interrogate the code to the extent that the compiler is.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. These are legal by the language specification.

Frankly, I'm not even seeing the subtle bugs that the examples you provide could cause.